# Divs are overlapping, how to fix? CSS

Tags: html, css, position, overlap

I want to position two divs next to each other which are below one another otherwise.

```
Div 1 Div 2
----  ----
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
----  ----
```

What ends up happening though with my code so far is that they overlap similar to this:

```
-----
|| ||
|| ||
-----
```

This is my code so far:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 40rem) and (max-width: 60rem) {
    #div1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
    }
    #div2 {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
    }
}
```

As you can see I want to place the div #div2 on the right, while the other one stays on the left.
Also I want this to happen only when the browser window is between 40 and 60 rem width.

But with my code they overlap. I want them to be placed neatly side by side.

Would be great if I could get some help.

Comment: float left, and float right is a possibility?

Comment: what are their widths, and what other CSS properties to they inherit from rules outside this media query ? A working demo will help a lot.

Comment: Doesn't work weirdly. Then the div2 will be placed below the div1.

Comment: @Gaby Should I post the entire code?

Comment: Seems like it is happening bc the screen is too small to contain both divs. I am not sure though. Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: I will post the code to jsfiddle.

EDIT: I don't think it would work since there are images involved.

Comment: EDIT: Really sorry, guys, have to go for about 2 hrs, will get back to you, thanks for the help so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 40rem) and (max-width: 60rem) {
    #div1 {
        float: left;
        width: 200px; /* change this value to your own needs */
    }
    #div2 {
        float: right;
        width: 200px; /* change this value to your own needs */
    }
}
```

*Next time, it would be really helpful to provide an example of your code in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)*

Answer (score 0):

The wrapper of the two divs isn't there or just isn't wide enough. This should work:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#leftDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}

#rightDiv {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftDiv">On the left side</div>
    <div id="rightDiv">On the right side</div>
</div>
```

You could also just float both the to the left, but I guess you need to use the absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You posted code will work just fine as it is, **if** the two divs can fit (*the sum of their widths*) side-by-side in the range between 40rem and 60rem

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/xb6smptx/1/

If they do not fit, then you might have to change the range of the media query, or change their widths in that media query to 50% as an example

```
@media screen and (min-width: 40rem) and (max-width: 60rem) {
    #div1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        width:20rem; /*example width that can fit side by side with the div2 width*/
    }
    #div2 {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        width:20rem; /*example width*/
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/xb6smptx/2/